# How to use glob to match and create a DataFrame with file name and path string from two folders

Tags: python

I have two folders that contain files with the same filenames but with different content and different file extensions. The only that is matching is the file name.

I want to create a DataFrame by matching those file names. The result should look like this:

| file_name_original | file_path_original | file_name_modified | file_path_modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| example.docx | home/dir/dir2 | example.csv | home/dir/dir1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I would like to use python for it or bash. Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use list comprehension with tuples then unpack them to a dataframe columns.

```py
from glob import glob
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

original_folder = sorted([(Path(x).name, str(Path(x).parent))
                          for x in glob('home/dir/dir2/*')])
mod_folder = sorted([(Path(x).name, str(Path(x).parent))
                     for x in glob('home/dir/dir1/*')])

# Optional line to make sure you have the same base names in both folders
assert all([[Path(x).stem
             for x in (x1, x2)] == [Path(x).stem for x in (y1, y2)]
            for (x1, x2), (y1, y2) in zip(original_folder, mod_folder)])

df = pd.DataFrame(original_folder,
                  columns=['file_name_original', 'file_path_original'])
df['file_name_modified'], df['file_path_modified'] = zip(*mod_folder)
```